# How to remove a word and following characters to the next coma

Tags: string, bash, sed

I have a string. Part of it contains **"Log":true.** which I would like to remove using bash and sed.

Original line

```
[...]\"Date\":\"1661731200000\",\"Log\":true,\"$$type\":\"system\",\"created\":\"2022-08-01T13:37:43+0[...]
```

Modified line

```
[...]\"Date\":\"1661731200000\",\"$$type\":\"system\",\"created\":\"2022-08-01T13:37:43+0[...]
```

I'm struggling to find the right expression. Is is possible to achieve it with sed?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Match `,\"Log\":` followed by any sequence of alphabetic characters.

```
sed 's/,\"Log\":[a-z]*//' filename
```

Comment: This is great, thank you.

I had to deal with the backslash escapes.

`cat filename | xargs echo -e | sed 's/,\"Log\":[a-z]*//'`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

cat << EOF >> edpop
2d
wq
EOF

cat file | tr ',' '\n' > file2
ed -s file2 < edpop
cat file2 | tr '\n' ',' > file

rm -v ./file2
rm -v ./edpop
```

This replaces the commas with newlines, deletes the second line with ed, (which corresponds with the second comma field) and then replaces the newlines with commas again.